# php write successful logins and unsuccessful to text file

Tags: php, forms, authentication, fwrite, fclose

I've been trying to write my successful logins/failed logins to a txt file but it doesn't work.

```
if($_POST['username']==$username && $_POST['password']==$password){

    $_SESSION['username']=$username;
    header('location:mainpage.php');
    $logInData = date('Ymd-H:i:s');
    $logLogIn = fopen("../logs/logins.txt", "a");
    $txt = "\r\n$logInData, You logged in Succesfully";
    fwrite($logLogIn, $txt);
    fclose($logLogIn);

}else{

    $err="Authentication Failed Try again!";
    $logInData = date('Ymd-H:i:s');
    $logLogIn = fopen("../logs/logins.txt", "a");
    $txt = "\r\n$logInData, Login failed wrong username or password";
    fwrite($logLogIn, $txt);
    fclose($logLogIn);

}
```

I get the following errors:

> **Warning:** fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/rans1600/public_html/D093G/moment2/index.php on line 32
>
> **Warning:** fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/rans1600/public_html/D093G/moment2/index.php on line 33
> Authentication Failed Try again!

Comment: this means fopen failed, debug that

Comment: sidenote: you sure you want to use that method of authenticating/login?

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn to troubleshoot issue.

I will give you pointers:

First you read the error:

> I get the following errors : Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to
>   be resource, **boolean given** in
>   /home/rans1600/public_html/D093G/moment2/index.php on line 32

You realize that `fopen()` is returning a boolean.

Then you check the [**fopen() documentation**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Notice the following is mentionned:

> Returns a file pointer resource on success, or **FALSE** on error.

also

> If the open fails, an error of level **E_WARNING** is generated. You may
>   use @ to suppress this warning.

Now you know what to do, display the warning, by putting the following at the first line of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```

Hopefully this will help you find the issue, which could be path issue, permission or whatever reason but why guess? You debugg it instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
$file = "../logs/logins.txt";
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= $_POST['username'] . ' ' . $_POST['password'] . "\n";
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

Comment: I've never said it's better. I tested it on my webserver and it worked fine.

Comment: his code would work on your server to, as its a permission\path issue

Answer (score -1):

Check the file permission and ownership of `logins.txt`.
It clearly means that there is problem with **"../logs/logins.txt"**

Post your server, OS and path of this PHP file please???